# How can I extract a std::string with boost.spirit?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

Using boost.spirit I try to parse simple command line of the form `command:param1 param2...`

to do so I created this parser:

```
(+(char_ - ':'))[ref(cmd) = _1]
>> ':'
>> (*char_)[ref(params) = _1]
```

The attribute types of the two compounds parser is vector, so if cmd and params are of type vector this work. However if they are of type std::string it doesn't. While searching for this solution on the web I found hint that it should also work with string. Is there anyway I can make this work with string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, when you use semantic actions no automatic attribute propagation will happen. Both your parsers (`+(char_ - ':')` and `*char_`) expose a `std::vector<char>` as their attribute. Therefore, `_1` refers to a `std::vector<char>` as well. If `cmd` and `params` are instances of `std::string` it will not compile as no assignment from a `std::vector<char>` to a `std::string` is defined.

However, if you get rid of the semantic actions it will work:

```
std::string s("command:param1 param2");
std::string cmd, params;
parse(s.begin(), s.end(), +~char_(':') >> ':' >> *char_, cmd, params);
```

This is not only simpler, but faster as well. The parser will place the matched characters directly into the supplied strings.